# Setting \parfillskip for every theorem-like environments

Tags: theorems, widows-orphans, parfillskip

To prevent the last line from being too short, I added `\setlength{\parfillskip}{0pt plus\dimexpr\linewidth-2\parindent}` to the preamble, and it works fine with normal paragraphs.

However, this setting does not work for lists and theorems. For list, with the package `enumitem`, I can do the following:

```
\setlist* { first* = \setlength { \parfillskip } { 0pt plus\dimexpr\linewidth-3em } }
```

What should I do for theorem-like environments, so as to prevent results like the following one? (Notice the single letter in the last line.)

[image]

---

***Background:** I'm using `amsthm` to define the theorems, and it would be quite helpful if someone knows how to set `\parfillskip` within a `\newtheoremstyle`; or, perhaps there is some internal macro that is carried out in the beginning of every theorem so that one may append the setting to it.*

Comment: The input should be `pour tout~$n$` anyway.

Comment: Rather than mess with \parfillskip, I would only change things if there was a problem, then just put the desired last line into an \hbox{}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside a `trivlist`, the `\parfillskip` is set to `\@flushglue` which has a default value of `0pt plus 1fil`. However this is also used in other situations, such as `raggedleft`, so changing it is not the best idea.

You can patch `\@trivlist` so the setting to `\parfillskip` is the same as for normal paragraphs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtheoremstyle{upbreak}
  {}
  {}
  {\upshape}
  {}
  {\bfseries}
  {.}
  {\newline}
  {}

\makeatletter
\newskip\nonfill@parfillskip
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \setlength{\nonfill@parfillskip}{0pt plus \dimexpr\columnwidth-2\parindent}%
  \setlength{\parfillskip}{\nonfill@parfillskip}%
}
\patchcmd{\@trivlist}{\@flushglue}{\nonfill@parfillskip}{}{}
\makeatother

\theoremstyle{upbreak}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-4] a.

\begin{theorem}
\hspace*{\parindent}\lipsum[1][1-4] a.
\end{theorem}

For demonstration purpose

\bigskip

\setlength{\parfillskip}{0pt plus 1fil}

\lipsum[1][1-4] a.

\end{document}
```

In the body of the theorem I added `\hspace*{\parindent}` so as to make the paragraphs to be exactly the same. At the end I show the typesetting of the same paragraph with the standard `\parfillskip`, for comparison.

Note that using `\linewidth` is not a good idea. The value of `\parfillskip` is not “dynamic” even if you use `\linewidth` in the code, because the value of `\linewidth` current at the moment of `\setlength` will be used. This is why I delay the setting at begin document, where the value of `\columnwidth` is known.

[image]

I purposefully didn't add a tie before `a.`, but in your example you should definitely have

```
pour tout~$n$.
```