# Strange extra space when \cref something defined with create-theorem with empty names

Tags: spacing, tex-core, debugging

Consider the following example, where I copied some code from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/641824).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newskip\nonfill@parfillskip
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \setlength{\nonfill@parfillskip}{0pt plus \dimexpr\columnwidth-2\parindent}%
  \setlength{\parfillskip}{\nonfill@parfillskip}%
}
\patchcmd{\@trivlist}{\@flushglue}{\nonfill@parfillskip}{}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{create-theorem}

\CreateTheorem{emptythm}{
    name = {
        heading = {EmptyTHM},
        crefname = {}{},
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{emptythm}\label{test}
    Test
\end{emptythm}

Text\cref{test}

Text \cref{test}

(\cref{test})

\end{document}
```

The reference gives the following result, which has strange extra spaces before the numbers:

[image]

If one comments the code modifying `\parfillskip`, the result becomes normal:

[image]

I'm not actually intend to do anything with `\parfillskip`. It's just that I'm very curious about why this would happen -- perhaps I have done something wrong in the package `create-theorem`. However, I have no idea how to debug in this situation: is there some way to tell what happens near the place of the whitespace and locate the corresponding code for it?

(*I'm asking this question because I found that, unlike usual references, when trying to `\cref` something defined with `create-theorem` with empty referencing names, the whitespace before it does not behave like the usual ones -- sometimes it is enlarged and sometimes it gets shrink, quite unpredictable, yet I'm not able to find out what is causing this*)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is a bug in your package. You are trying to undo a space by inserting a negative skip but you forgot the stretch and shrink part. As they remain they are stretched to fullfill the `\parfillskip` requirement. Why don't you use simply `\unskip` instead?

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% from \crefthe_empty_adjust:n
\newcommand\minusspace{\skip_horizontal:n { -\tex_fontdimen:D 2 \tex_font:D }}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document} 
\showoutput

Text \minusspace blub

\parfillskip=0pt plus \dimexpr\columnwidth-2\parindent\relax

Text \minusspace blub

\ExplSyntaxOn
\renewcommand\minusspace{\skip_horizontal:n { -\tex_fontdimen:D 2 \tex_font:D~plus -\tex_fontdimen:D 3 \tex_font:D~minus -\tex_fontdimen:D 4 \tex_font:D }}
\ExplSyntaxOff
Text \minusspace blub

Text \unskip blub

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! May I ask one more question: if one wishes to get the negative of `-\tex_fontdimen:D 2 \tex_font:D~plus -\tex_fontdimen:D 3 \tex_font:D~minus -\tex_fontdimen:D 4 \tex_font:D`, should one just remove the first `-` sign or all the three? By experiment it seems to be just removing the first one, but I would like to be sure about this.

Comment: look into the log. \showoutput shows you which glues are inserted.